# What is the proper way to format time so that Lint doesnt complain about implicitly using the default locale?

Tags: android, format

My situation:
I just want to format minutes and seconds into a time clock text format.
When i use String.format i get the warning
"implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs"

How am I supposed to handle this? Do I have to add Locale.US or can I ignore this?
I am confused because in no answer i see anyone using String.format(Locale.US, ...)

```
private void updateCountDownText() {

    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

Comment: Calendar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is just a warning not an error. The reason for this warning is that for different Locales the same operation can lead to different results in some rare cases. You have to options to make this warning disappear:

1. add ignore annotation

   ```
   @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
   ```
2. explicitly put Locale parameter

   ```
   String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Won't Locale.getDefault() have the exact same effect as not passing a Locale? And wouldn't it be possible that the formatting fails for some default locales? I wonder if it is better to pass Locale.US so i can be sure that it shows tha clock as i want.

Comment: Yes, it will have the same effect, but Lint will be happy with it ;-) And if your app is designed for US then passing that locale should be ok, too